# How to keep useful but rarely used apps uninstalled in the phone (ready-to-install, ideally including their settings)?

Tags: applications, application-manager, file-archives

Currently I have installed ~500 apps, mostly productivity apps and tools of various types.

I would like to have only ~100 most frequent apps installed and keep the rest (~400) uninstalled, stored in the file system along with their settings. If needed, I would like to restore such a stored app (ideally including its settings), use it and when no longer needed, archive + uninstall again.

The sample of such an app is a Latin lexicon or some infrequently used measurement tool.

**Is there an app or some procedure for this task?** Or the truth is that there is no tool which can easily backup and restore *settings* of 3rd-party apps (only the APKs themselves)? Could you refer to a tool who could at least partially automate this? At least some APK install+deinstall tool keeping user-friendly record about each app and showing **Archive**/**Restore** button next to it?

---

The reason of my expectation is unnecessarily high battery consumption with ~500 installed apps, because many of them also install their own services, slowing down the device. I want to have them at hand if needed (including their settings) but normally keep them away from the OS.

The phone is not rooted.

Comment: I have the same problem, not 500 or so apps but many apps which I don't use regularly. Since my device is rooted, I use the app Apptoggle. It is a straightforward app to disable or enable an app on the fly. Let me know if this solution is acceptable to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only non-root app I'm aware of for that would be [Helium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup), which lets you backup and restore apps including their data. Catch: apps can opt-out of this kind of backup, which uses `adb backup` behind the scenes – so this might only cover parts of the apps you wish to deal with, and you must make sure the backup really worked before deleting an app you want to restore later.

All other approaches I'm aware of require root.

But be welcome to take a look at my [list of battery savers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_batterysaver); some "hibernators" might work, too (even without root). Battery-wise I'd expect such a "hibernator" to have the intended effect – while with Helium+uninstall I'm pretty sure (what's not installed cannot use resources). Years ago, when I still had GApps on my device, I used Greenify to hibernate Google Maps, which was permanentĺy active in background though I rarely even started it. Effect was as intended.

Comment: I am accepting this as a valid approach, generally viable for most devices. In my specific case, I also explored [Firelord's comment above](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209653/how-to-keep-useful-but-rarely-used-apps-uninstalled-in-the-phone-ready-to-insta?noredirect=1#comment268995_209653) and based on it I found there is a *no-root* solution for Samsung devices, app [Package Disabler Pro+ (Samsung)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.elmklmsamsung.batteryaddon) which solves the enablement/disablement on Samsung devices by creative use of their Knox feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to Settings > Backup & reset > set Back up my data to ON. Set/select a backup account, then enable Automatic restore.

If the phone was rooted, [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en) is probably what you should try.

> You can backup, restore, freeze (with Pro) your apps + data + Market links. This includes all protected apps & system apps, plus external data on your SD card.

From its [website](https://www.titaniumtrack.com/titanium-backup.html):

> Titanium Backup is a backup utility for Android that backs up your system and user applications along with their data on external storage of your choice

Edit: OP could also use `adb backup` as described on [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/28315/247431)

Edit 2: Below is the response I received from Google Product Forum after asking if the backup data of a removed app are removed during the next sync,

[image: Response from Google Product Forum]

Comment: Please what is the basis of the first paragraph? Per my understanding, if I back up settings ("Back up my data" = ON) and then de-install their app, aren't the data (here with focus on settings) deleted from the backup on next sync, considered to be no longer needed?

Comment: If that's the Google Cloud backup, then 1) apps must support it and 2) you cannot "restore on demand" – plus especially you cannot restore selected apps. Restore only happens at re-initialization after a factory reset, if at all (and only for apps you haven't deleted). And what will be restored varies from nothing via some to most. This definitely doesn't fit the requirement. And as for TiBu (which would do this wonderfully), OP explicitly wrote the device is not rooted. I use TiBu myself for almost 10 years now and won't miss it – but miroslav cannot do so.

Comment: Per my understanding ([Backup & restore](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2819582?hl=en), the backups should be still be there after sync even if you deleted the app. But will research, and report back. @Izzy That's why I wrote: "If the phone was rooted.." :)

Comment: Yes, I saw the conditional. Didn't delete the answer :) If you figure a way to restore single apps from a GCloud backup on-demand, or even apps you explicitely deleted, and that for end-users, I guess there are many who'd like to know that solution. To my knowledge: "fat chance". I gladly stand corrected – even though I'd never backup my stuff to the cloud, or even use GApps on my devices :)

Comment: @Izzy I never use Backup & restore. I go with Titanium Backup because I prefer to keep my backups local. I have queried in Google Products Forum the question asked by OP about the backup data being possibly deleted after sync if app was removed. No answer so far.